# App uses the Launcher Icon as Notification Icon on some phones

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-icons

I am testing my app on some phones.

When testing on LG, Samsung, and Kodak phones, (ranging from Android 5 to 7)the icon was the one I picked for notifications, a map like icon.
[image: Correct icon]
However, on all Huawei and a Xiaomi device I tried it on(also many OSs), the notification icon that appeared was the launcher icon, which at the time was an Android robot 
[image: Wrong Icon]

I used the built-in image asset studio to create the icon, following these instructions https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html#create-notification
The code for the notification is here:

```
    public void crenot(float walk){
    Notification noti  = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("Your daily result ")
        .setContentText("You walked "+Float.toString(walk/1000)+" km today")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.map_not)
        .build();
    NotificationManager notman=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notman.notify(0,noti);}
```

I can't find a solution on google. I found this,
[Android notification displays wrong icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40317819/android-notification-displays-wrong-icon)
 but I am not sure how I should change my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`setSmallIcon()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setSmallIcon(int)) is used to set the icon in the status bar as said in the documentation.

If you want to set the icon in the notification drawer, add [`setLargeIcon()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setLargeIcon(android.graphics.Bitmap)) to your `Notification.Builder`:

```
.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.map_not))
```